# Excel - How to automatically highlight cells when a cell with equivalent value is highlighted

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I have a "master list". We'll say it looks like so:

> A | C | E
>
> B | D | F

Next we have a larger list like so:

> A | C | E
>
> A | D | E
>
> B | D | E

In the master list, I want to be able to highlight A or B, and all A's or B's in the column below will be subsequently highlighted the same color. Then I want to move on to C and D with the same results.

I have done some research and I believe Conditional Formatting may be the way to go here, but I'm not sure. I also thought about VLOOKUP, but I'm very new to the formula.

Comment: Just to clarify: These example show three columns? Not a single string in each cell which contains "A | C | E"?

Comment: More questions: do you want to restrict the coloring to the same column? Is your formatting consistent? That is, once A = "Yellow" is it always yellow, or are you asking the ability for A's color to change anytime another A's color in the same column changes?

Comment: Correct, three columns. I used A-F as generic values, I'll really be using Cities. Each column will consist of one of the two A or B values. When I highlight one in the "master list" it does the same for all the rest in that column. Saves me from highlighting hundreds of times.

Comment: The sheet is for picking sports teams to win. So I shade green the winning team in the master list, then all the other people's choices follow suit green for correct and red for incorrect. A and B will only be present in the first column, never in the rest as there is only one game to play at that time.

Comment: You will be better off with putting the value in a cell and then use CF to check for that value (and color it) due to the fact that CF can not check for colors. Another aproach would be a simple filter and then color them manually.

Answer (score 0):

So, for the generic condition you initially asked, there are ways to do this using a VBA macro, but even they are not perfect, and they can get very complicated. In fact, there is no direct way in Excel to check to see if the color of a cell has changed (See here: [Capturing Cell Color Change](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/574405-capturing-cell-color-change-visual-basic-applications.html)).  I think the simplest thing to do would be to change the way you do things slightly, and it will work better for your application.

Add a row (or two, if you want a blank one for separation) above your columns. In row A, you will type the name of the winning team - then all of the values below will highlight based on whether it is the winning team or the losing team.

To do this:

1. Highlight your entire list (I'm going to assume this range begins with A3, and your winning teams will start with A1)
2. Select "Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cell Rules -> Equal To"
3. In the left box, type `=A$1` (EXACTLY AS WRITTEN). In the right box, select the highlighting you want for the winning team.
4. Click OK
5. Select "Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cell Rules -> More Rules
6. In the middle box, select "not equal to" and in the right box type `=A$1` (EXACTLY AS WRITTEN).
7. Click Format... and select the highlighting you want for the losing team. 8. Click OK

When the winning team is decided, type the winners into Row A, and the highlighting will occur automatically (Note: this will assume they're all losers until you enter a winner).

FYI: The dollar sign "anchors" that column or row (row 1 in this case). So as it checks each cell, it always checks row 1, but since the A doesn't have the dollar sign, it will check the column it is in.

I think this is the best solution for your situation. If you still want to get the answer to exactly what you asked (or at least closer to it) and you're not afraid to dive into macros, let me know and I can post some code that might work for you.